# Can't find protected folder in Yii2 Basic Package

Tags: php, yii2, config

I'm new to Yii2 and I was wondering where the protected/config/main.php sitting? Is web.php the main config file?

Answer (score 1):

Respect to yii1   the (in part) configuration  is in

```
basic\config\web.php
```

and part is in

```
basic\config\db.php
```

There is also an advanced template where you have frontend and backend application soon available  with proper separated  config area ..